# Kafka .net client does not receive any messages when using Assign()

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am trying to make my service re-read kafka topic from the beginning to the end on start to initialize internal data structures. I am using Confluent .NET client. 
From my understanding the following code should subscribe me on topic setting offset to the beginning:

```
consumer.Assign(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, Partition.Any, Offset.Beginning));
```

But for some reason I don't receive not the messages pre-existent in topic, not the new ones.
Is my understanding of Assign() method wrong? Is there a way to achieve the desired result using Subscribe() without need for hard reset of offsets using kafka CLI?

Here is the full test client, the output I have is always 'No messages...' despite the fact that topic has messages and new messages are arriving.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConsumerConfig
        {
            BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
            GroupId = "test-consumer",
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest,
        };
        var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Null, byte[]>(config).Build();
        var topic = "test-topic";
        consumer.Assign(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, Partition.Any, Offset.Beginning));
        while (true)
        {
            var result = consumer.Consume(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            if (result == null)
                Console.WriteLine("No messages...");
            else
                Console.WriteLine($"Offset: {result.Offset}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Plase remove `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)` from `consumer.Consume`...then try again...let me know if that works :)

Comment: It just freezes forever on consumer.Consume() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the I called Assign() with Partition.Any, the following code works:
`consumer.Assign(new TopicPartitionOffset(topic, new Partition(0), Offset.Beginning));`

Answer (score 0):

Why would you like to use `Assign`? The following should work for you:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var conf = new ConsumerConfig
    { 
        GroupId = "test-consumer",
        BootstrapServers = "localhost:9092",
        AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
    };

    using (var c = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, string>(conf).Build())
    {
        c.Subscribe("test-topic");

        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (_, e) => {
            e.Cancel = true; // prevent the process from terminating.
            cts.Cancel();
        };

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    var cr = c.Consume(cts.Token);
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message '{cr.Value}' at: '{cr.TopicPartitionOffset}'.");
                }
                catch (ConsumeException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {e.Error.Reason}");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            c.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This will read events from the last committed offset. My aim is to re-read all events from the beginning.

Comment: @AlexeyUkolov This is controlled by `AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest`. If you change the `GroupId` to `"test-consumer-2"` (i.e. a new/previously unseen consumer group) you will be able to read the messages from the very beginning. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlexeyUkolov Let me know if this has worked for you so I can update my answer.

Comment: AutoOffsetReset kicks in only if the last committed offset is no longer available.

Comment: Changing group Id Could work, but then I'll need create new group IDs all the time. Assign() method does not create subscription group in zookeeper, that's why I was trying to use it instead of Subscribe ().

Comment: @AlexeyUkolov I see this is an old question, but do you know any way to Assign with Partition.Any? Looks like Partition.Any doesn't work